# schwa sound /mən/ sounds like /mæn/ in some dialects?

Tags: pronunciation

Most of the dictionaries online pronounce the word `fireman` the way I expected, but one of them's American pronunciation sounds like /ˈfaɪə(r)mæn/ even though the IPA is still /ˈfaɪə(r)mən/.

Is possible that it's a peculiarity in some American dialects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where I am from, midwest United States, /ˈfaɪə(r)mæn/ would be a more careful pronunciation while
/ˈfaɪə(r)mən/ would be what you are most likely to say in casual speech when talking a little more quickly.

The benefit of the more careful pronunciation is that you manage to explicitly distinguish a singular firefighter – a fire**man** – from a group of them – fire**men**.

Alternatively, you could use /ˈfaɪə(r)mæn/ to distinguish a male firefighter from a female one (a firewoman).

Comment: As a side note, I believe [firefighter is taking over](https://tinyurl.com/yxpu8ask) as the term for *those who fight fires* these days (as it's gender neutral). I also think [*female firefighter* is the preferred term](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=firewoman%2Cfemale+firefighter&year_start=1900&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfirewoman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfemale%20firefighter%3B%2Cc0) rather than firewoman (which saw a lot of use in WW2 era) probably relating to the gender neutral term

Comment: I know that personally I always tend to say firefighter, although it's not a conscious choice to be gender neutral; it's just what I say. I don't know anyone who really says firewoman, but then again it's not a word that has the opportunity to come up very often either.